# LibreOffice Writer is erasing my document's line spacing after I save and close

Tags: libreoffice

Every time I open the document, it defaults to double spacing. I highlight parts of it, change it to single spacing, save it, restart LibreOffice Writer, and all the text is double spaced. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: what Style/formatting is set (f11)?

Comment: Default Style before and after I change to single spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Under [format] [paragraph] check [Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style]

Comment: please don't vote to "recommend deletion". this is the correct answer.

Comment: I just tried this out and it didn't seem to work. I'm running 14.04 if that's relevant. This is odd.

Answer (score 0):

this is really old but incase you're still having problems, select the paragraph youre trying to single-space, right click and hit Clear Direct Formatting, it should work fine now

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting "Line Spacing: Single", select "Proportional: 100%". When you save, quit, and reopen, the setting will now be set to "Line Spacing: Single"